# Rechartd: Vertical bar chart - set bar thickness

Tags: reactjs, recharts

How to set the bars thickness?

```
<ResponsiveContainer width='100%' aspect={4.0 / 3.0}>
                        <BarChart data={data} layout="vertical">
                            <XAxis type="number" hide />
                            <YAxis dataKey="name" hide reversed type="category" />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <Bar legendType="star" dataKey="1" fill="#ff6f31" />
                            <Bar legendType="star" dataKey="2" fill="#ff9f02" />
                            <Bar legendType="star" dataKey="3" fill="#ffcf02" />
                            <Bar legendType="star" dataKey="4" fill="#99cc00" />
                            <Bar legendType="star" dataKey="5" fill="#88b131" />
                        </BarChart>
                    </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Current Result

[image]

Data set

```
[{1: 0, name: "1"},
{2: 0, name: "2"},
{3: 1, name: "3"},
{4: 1, name: "4"},
{5: 2, name: "5"}]
```

Answer (score 11):

By using the barSize key in the Bar tag:

```
<Bar dataKey="pv" barSize={20} fill="#8884d8" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `barSize` api to set width on each Bar element

Refer [Recharts-Bar](http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/Bar) for more reference and examples

Answer (score 1):

Use `barCategoryGap={30} barGap={5}`

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.